# Appium Inspector Version 1.4.16.1 Error:- Failed to connect to to server, Pls check that it is running

Tags: android, testing, appium

Using Appium on my windows 10 and Geny Motion 2.5.4 for emulator .
I am not able to Use Appium Inspector. 
my appium Version is 1.4.16.1.
I been running my appium Inspector while running my Test Code.
then also it gives error "Failed to connect to to server, Pls check that it is running".
I have set all the Capabilities in my code.
Plzz help me to solve this issue.

my appium log

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"D:\_Projects\_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk","appPackage":"FormsGallery.Android","appActivity":"md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity","BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Emulator"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : BROWSER_NAME, VERSION
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_60
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device 10.71.34.101:5555
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to 10.71.34.101:5555
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: Device API level is: 19
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: en
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk" "C:\Users\User02\AppData\Local\Temp\FormsGallery.Android" en
>   info: [debug] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk" "C:\Users\User02\AppData\Local\Temp\FormsGallery.Android"
>   info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 push "C:\Users\User02\AppData\Local\Temp\FormsGallery.Android\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe dump xmltree "D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk" AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: FormsGallery.Android
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" "D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk"
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign.exe
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign.exe -f 4 "D:_Projects_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk" C:\Users\User02\AppData\Local\Temp\1151123-9176-1ommac3\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is ac894dad9066f52ce250cb57ead31bc9
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/ac894dad9066f52ce250cb57ead31bc9.apk"
>   info: [debug] Getting install status for FormsGallery.Android
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "pm list packages -3 FormsGallery.Android"
>   info: [debug] App is installed
>   info: App is already installed, resetting app
>   info: [debug] Running fast reset (stop and clear)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "am force-stop FormsGallery.Android"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "pm clear FormsGallery.Android"
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg FormsGallery.Android -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] json loading complete.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "dumpsys window"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"/data","status":0}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n FormsGallery.Android/md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity"
>   info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "FormsGallery.Android" and activity "md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity" to be focused
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 10.71.34.101:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
>   info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.4.4
>   info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
>   info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
>   info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 6194.012 ms - 74 
>   info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027 {}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.4","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"D:\_Projects\_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk","appPackage":"FormsGallery.Android","appActivity":"md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity","BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Emulator"},"app":"D:\_Projects\_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk","appPackage":"FormsGallery.Android","appActivity":"md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity","BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"10.71.34.101:5555"},"sessionId":"091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027"}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027 200 7.728 ms - 870 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.4","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"app":"D:\_Projects\_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk","appPackage":"FormsGallery.Android","appActivity":"md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity","BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Emulator"},"app":"D:\_Projects\_Test Automation\FormsGallery.Android-Signed.apk","appPackage":"FormsGallery.Android","appActivity":"md529130983bd62f4112a07211b98c3bfae.MainActivity","BROWSER_NAME":"Android","VERSION":"4.4.4","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"10.71.34.101:5555"},"sessionId":"091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027/window/current/maximize {"windowHandle":"current"}
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027/window/current/maximize 200 4.618 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027"}
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>   info: [debug] Error: Requested a new session but one was in progress
>       at [object Object].Appium.start (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:139:15)
>       at exports.createSession (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:188:16)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\controller.js:39:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:104:14)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at methodOverride (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\method-override\index.js:79:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at logger (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:136:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
>       at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:111:5
>       at done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:248:14)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:294:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
>       at _stream_readable.js:908:16
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress)","origValue":"Requested a new session but one was in progress"},"sessionId":"091854d6-22d5-4483-a64e-86593cc7b027"}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 11.658 ms - 250

Answer (score 1):

Use UIAutomator under Android sdk>tools. It serves the same purpose as Appium inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual error is `Original error: Requested a new session but one was in progress`
This means your last session didn't quit properly. Be sure to use driver.quit() when your test is finished. 
To fix this before you run your next test, simply stop and restart the appium server.